# Mongo shows new collections and databases after restoration from backup

Tags: mongodb, backup, rsync

I've created a backup process for the mongo dbdir. 
The restoration process takes one of the backups created by rsync and copies it to a new disk and mounts it on the data dir.

After the process I still see collections and databases (databases appear as empty) that existed before the restoration process, until I restart mongo. 
I would like to avoid this restart if possible,

is there any way to cause mongo reload its data files on the fly? 
(I didn't use mongodump because it for some reason inflated the db from 4GB to 40GB after mongorestore, but that is a different issue)

Answer (score 1):

Using *rsync* on a running mongod dbpath may result in corruption or unexpected errors. Please refer to [MongoDB Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/) for supported backup and restore alternatives.

While using *rsync*, please consider the following suggestion from [MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/#backup-by-copying-underlying-data-files):

> If your storage system does not support snapshots, you can copy the files directly using cp, rsync, or a similar tool. Since copying multiple files is not an atomic operation, you must **stop all writes to the mongod before copying the files**. Otherwise, you will copy the files in an invalid state.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I saw the methods, but non of them offered an incremental solution, and trying to use oplog as an incremental backup resulted in very large backup. the problem by the way was wrong storage engine.